# How to store data in dcc.store from multiple callbacks

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, plotly-python

In my dash app, there is a data-table with data coming from different endpoints using rest API ( Endpoints are selected from a drop-down list)
So whenever user selects a new endpoint, data gets stored in browser session using `dcc.store()` from a callback as below

```
@app.callback(Output('store-id', 'data'), Input('endpoint-name', 'value'))
def store_data(iData):
    return iData
```

My data-table is editable (with drop-down options) and I have a save button below the data table from where I want to save the modified data into the session store. But I cannot figure out a way how this second call_back will store/ replace data in same `dcc.store` as Dash do not allow duplicate callback Output

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to find callbacks sharing the same output/s, then it might be worthwhile combining the callbacks into one. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820651/dash-callback-preventing-other-callbacks/68890236#68890236) explaining how to usually design callbacks that I follow.